# Bash create regex/wildcard link

Tags: regex, bash

I'm trying to create a link but I only know the first part of the folder name. For example:

```
ln -s /root/v1.0.{?}/bin /usr/bin/myapp
```

In the above I know that it starts with a `v1.0` but don't know the `patch` version. I'm curious if it's possible to build a symbolic link like this?

Comment: There's a possible misunderstanding here: it's possible to use a wildcard when creating the link (see answers below), but the wildcard won't be part of the link -- the shell will evaluate the wildcard, pass the existing version to `ln -s`, and that'll make a link to that version. If you later upgrade to a newer version, the link will still be pointing to the old version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't test it right now, since I'm not on a Linux system at the moment, but as far as I know from bash's autocompletion features, `ln -s /root/v1.0.*/bin /usr/bin/myapp` should do the trick - under the premise, that there's only one folder matching that wildcard. You might want to consider using `ln -sv` instead of `ln -s` so you can see if it works and if the link points to the right position.

Comment: You might use plain `?` instead of `*` for single-digit version numbers.  Playing with `./name-{?}.c` with Bash 3.2 on Mac, I get some interesting effects.  With just the `?`, the generated name is `./name-{?}.c`; with `./name-{?,@,=}.c`, I get `./name-1.c ./name-2.c ./name-@.c ./name-=.c` in the directory where I do have files `./name-1.c` and `./name-2.c`.  There's something weird going on there. I guess I should re-reread the Bash manual on [brace expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Brace-Expansion) _[…continued…]_

Comment: _[…continuation…]_  And there's the answer: _A correctly-formed brace expansion must contain unquoted opening and closing braces, and at least one unquoted comma or a valid sequence expression. Any incorrectly formed brace expansion is left unchanged._  So you can't use the braces when there's a single option.  You either need at least one comma or something like `{1..10}`.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is correct, just remove braces part from it. '?' is a wild character and it should work fine. provided your directory structure is as below:
/root/v1.0.0/bin
/root/v1.0.1/bin
which will work fine until v1.0.9

ln -s /root/v1.0.?/bin /usr/bin/myapp

but if versioning is more than 9 then, you should rather change the wild character from ? to *

but if you have specific versioning structure and it is always going to be a number.
I would rather suggest you to use below

ln -s /root/v1.0.[0-9]*/bin /usr/bin/myapp

here it will create a link in myapp directory.

hope it would help you in future.